# How can I make a search that is filtered by multiple inputs in Laravel 4.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want this form to search multiple fields. How can I aggregate these search terms and filter them by their appropriate fields?

For example, if the user types "Book" into the textsearch field, and then selects "Assigned" from the status dropdown, the page should return all requests containing 'book' in the subject or details field, and 'assigned' in the status field.

I have the following form in my Laravel 4.2 Application:

```
    {{ Form::open(['route' => 'requests.search']) }}
    <!-- Text Search Form Input -->
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('textsearch', 'Text Search:') }}
        {{ Form::text('textsearch', $query, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
        {{ Form::hidden('search', 'text') }}
    </div>
    <!-- Status Form Input -->
    <div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('status', 'Status:') }}
    {{ Form::select('status', $statuses, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
    </div>
    <!-- Category Form Input -->
    <div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('category', 'Category:') }}
    {{ Form::select('category', $categories, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
    </div>
    <!-- Teamleader Form Input -->
    <div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('teamleader', 'Team Leader:') }}
    {{ Form::select('teamleader', $projectmembers, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
    </div>
    <!-- Requestid Form Input -->
    <div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('requestid', 'Request ID:') }}<br/>
    <span>Between:</span>
    {{ Form::text('requestidstart', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'width:100%;']) }}
    <span>And:</span>
    {{ Form::text('requestidend', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'width:100%;'])}}
    </div>
    <!-- Requestdate Form Input -->
    <div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('requestdate', 'Request Date:') }}<br/>
    <span>From:</span>
    {{ Form::text('requestdatestart', null, ['class' => 'form-control etadatepicker', 'style' => 'width:100%;']) }}
    <span>To:</span>
    {{ Form::text('requestdateend', null, ['class' => 'form-control etadatepicker', 'style' => 'width:100%;'])}}
    </div>
    <!-- Requestduedate Form Input -->
    <div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('requestduedate', 'Due Date:') }}<br/>
    <span>From:</span>
    {{ Form::text('requestduedatestart', null, ['class' => 'form-control etadatepicker', 'style' => 'width:100%;']) }}
    <span>To:</span>
    {{ Form::text('requestduedateend', null, ['class' => 'form-control etadatepicker', 'style' => 'width:100%;'])}}
    </div>
    {{ Form::submit('Search') }}
    {{ Form::close() }}<br/>
```

Controller:

```
$requestresponsetype = ['' => ''] + RequestResponseType::lists('description', 'description');
$projectmembers = ['' => ''] + RequestProjectMember::lists('first_name', 'first_name');
$statuses = ['' => ''] + RequestStatus::lists('description', 'description');
$categories = ['' => ''] + RequestCategory::lists('description', 'description');
$query = Input::get('textsearch');
$requests = DataRequest::where("subject", "LIKE", "%$query%")->orWhere("details", "LIKE", "%$query%")->orWhere("id","LIKE","%$query%")->paginate(10);
return View::make('requests.index', ['requests' => $requests, 'statuses' => $statuses, 'requestresponsetype' => $requestresponsetype, 'projectmembers' => $projectmembers, 'categories' => $categories, 'query' => $query]);
```

Comment: Can you add additional information such as whether all the information comes from one table for your design? if not, add the relationship and table design so that I can see what needs to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your idea clearly, but I guess something like:

```
$requests = DataRequest::where(function($q) {
    $q->where("subject", "LIKE", "%$query%")
      ->orWhere("details", "LIKE", "%$query%")
      ->orWhere("id","LIKE","%$query%");
})
->where('status', '=', $status)
->paginate(10);
```

In my project, I created a scope to search, it's reuseable and readable.

```
//BaseModel
public function scopeSearch($query, $search, $fields)
{
    $query->where(function($q) use ($search, $fields) {
        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            $q->orWhere($field, "LIKE", "%$search%");
        }
    }
}

$requests = DataRequest::search($query, ["subject", "details", "id"])
->where('status', '=', $status)
->paginate(10);
```

Comment: This is a good solution for multiple fields, but I also have multiple inputs. I have several text inputs, several dropdowns etc... What I need to know is how to aggregate multiple queries from multiple inputs, and then filter the page by all of them, disregarding inputs that the user left blank.

Comment: I think you can add a loop for multiple inputs with my example.